# Trying to print username at message of the day (MOTD)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh

I'm testing a simple script that prints a welcome message to users that are login in a server.

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
_user=$(whoami)
_hostname=$(hostname)
_currdate=$(date)

echo "#===================================================#"
echo "          Welcome $_user to $_hostname server"
echo "          Curr. time: $_currdate"
echo "          Have a nice day!"
echo " "
echo  "#==================================================#"
```

I'm saving the script at **/etc/update-motd.d/**, so that the message appears after the user login. **The problem is** that the var `_user` always appears as "**root**" and i can't find a way to get the username from the user. I'm testing this via SSH.

Can somebody help me ? 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grawity's answer is incorrect. He states that the motd is a global file, but the OP clearly stated he was working in /etc/update-motd.d/.

/etc/update-motd.d/ allows for dynamically generated MOTDs and can run actual scripts or applications.

That beeing said, I was facing the same issue as you. The issue is that during the execution of the MOTD, the priviledges haven't dropped to the user account yet, so all scripts are ran as root.

I managed to find a solution that works on Debian machines. I didnt try it on other distributions. What my solution does it retrieve the username from the 'ps' output, as sshd shows the username, such as:

```
root      4179  0.0  0.0  93984  5952 ?        Ss   10:44   0:00 sshd: johndoe [priv]
```

My little script 'searches back' in the process tree to find the process that contains the username.

```
PPID1=`cat /proc/$PPID/status | grep PPid | awk '{ print $2 }'`
PPID2=`cat /proc/$PPID1/status | grep PPid | awk '{ print $2 }'`
USERNAME=`ps -x | grep $PPID2 | awk '{ print $6 }' |  sed "s/[[:digit:].-]//g"`
```

The username is now in the $USERNAME variable.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu Zesty

Comment: This worked on Raspbian (with zsh) when the accepted answer didn't.

Comment: Note, `USERNAME` is a special parameter in zsh. Setting it may have unwanted side effects. I may suggest to change to `username`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. The motd is a *global* file, shared among users (it's /etc/motd), and updated only on reboot (and once in a while I guess). So there can't be anything user-specific or session-specific.

Instead, add your messages to `/etc/profile` to be shown by the shell:

```
if [ -t 1 ] && [ ! -f ~/.hushlogin ]; then
    echo "Welcome to $(hostname), $(whoami)!"
    echo "$(ddate). Have a nice day."
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @grawity. I'm a begginer in scripting. Can you explain me, please, your if statement?

Comment: @tzlima: Read through the manual pages of `test` (aka `[`), or of the `bash` shell. The first check is whether output is to a terminal (to avoid cluttering _batch_ connections with garbage messages); the second is whether the user has chosen to _hide_ the motd by creating a `~/.hushlogin` file.

Comment: @grawity is imprecise by saying that it is a global file.  Yes, it is a global file, but it is a global file that is read by users that log in.  The problem the OP is seeing isn't that it is a global file; the problem is that when motd is shown, it is shown as the user root and not the logged in user.  The solution offered is ok, though.  I *think* at the time motd is shown, there is no variable for the logged in user.  (I'm trying to find it too.)

Answer (score 1):

Following wont work for local logins, but then again my motd doesn't pop on local logins for me and the OP is looking for an SSH related solution; so here's the magic incantation for capturing the username of the latest user to have logged in via SSH to a variable within a motd script.

```
_user="$(grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log | awk '/Accepted publickey for/{print $9}' | tail -1)"
```

> Correction, `grep` doesn't seem to be required...

```
_user="$(awk '/Accepted publickey for/ {print $9}' /var/log/auth.log | tail -1)"
```

Though I'm not sure what'll be reported if/when two or more users login at the same time; so don't rely on it for security or for privacy to be maintained.

Comment: for me it worked after peeking into the log file and adjusting the search string in the script to  ```_user="$(grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log | awk '/session opened for user/{print $11}' | tail -1)"```